# SQL on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sorry if this question has been asked many times but the solutions that have worked for other people do not seem to be working for me.

I have 8 tables and I am trying to get a count of the id's in all 8 tables.

My code is:

```
SELECT cs.SYS_LOC_CODE INTO tmp_FINAL
FROM dt cs
    INNER JOIN table1 fv
    ON cs.ID = fv.ID
    INNER JOIN table2  v3
    ON ff.ID = v3.ID
    INNER JOIN table3  ppi
    ON v3.ID = ppi.ID
    INNER JOIN table4  pu
    ON ppi.ID = pu.ID
    INNER JOIN table5  s
    ON pu.ID = s.ID
    INNER JOIN table6  t
    ON s.ID = t.ID
    INNER JOIN table7 sv1
    ON t.ID= sv1.ID;
```

Then I do a count(*) on the table and I get a number that is way too big because it exceeds the count of the minimum table size.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcom to SO. I don't see a count here but I have a feeling this isn't really the query you were trying. My guess would be that you have multiple rows in some of the joined tables so your counts are not what you think they should be. Here is a great place to start to improve your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Table relationships aren't always 1:1, there are also 1:Many relationships, and also Many to Many relationships. Welcome to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH IDS AS (
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS IDCOUNT FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS IDCOUNT FROM table2
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS IDCOUNT FROM table8
)
SELECT SUM(IDCOUNT) FROM IDS
```

Replace "UNION ALL" statement by "UNION" if you don't want that same IDs from different tables are counted multiple times.
Replace "COUNT(ID)" by "COUNT(DISTINCT ID)" if you don't want that same IDs in a single table are counted multiple times.